# What does fully modded mean in terms of Dota 2 Items?

Tags: dota-2

Can  someone  explain  me  what it means if an Item is fully modified in Dota 2  ?
Like  Odachi  full  mod for example.

Answer (score 8):

Full mod means that the item (in that case the [Fireborn Odachi](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Fireborn_Odachi) for Juggernaut) has been [socketed](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Socket) with the maximum amount of [gems](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Gem) possible.

With your example :

The [Kinetic gem](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Kinetic_Gem#Juggernaut) that gives a custom animation to blade fury and the 3 [Inscribed gems](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Inscribed_Gem#Juggernaut) that respectively track the *number of Omnislash jumps*, the *amount of blade fury damage* and the *number of blade dance crits*.

Comment: as usual, your answer is better than mine, but still it is Juggernaut not naught? Isn't it? ;)

Comment: @RayofCommand right, I always want to spell it like dreadnought, I don't know why

Comment: Each socketable item can hold up to 5 applicable gems. So with that Juggernaut item with 1 kinetic gem + 3 Juggernaut-specific gems in your example, you could have a 5th gem to be _really_ "full mod". It'd have to be [something universal](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Inscribed_Gem#Universal_Gems) though, like "kills".

Answer (score 1):

It's related to dota 2 items. You can modify your items. Odachi Fireborn, correct me if I am wrong, is a Yunero Juggernaut Dota 2 Sword.

Full mod means fully modified aka maximum modified (max gems socketed)

Here you can see more about it :

[dota 2 trade screenshots odachi mod](http://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http://media.dota-trade.com/img/screenshots/l/f/fireborn-odachi-arb3lq8zs.jpg&imgrefurl=http://de.dota-trade.com/fireborn-odachi-item&h=594&w=821&tbnid=5ZEr4ZjHbpA5JM:&zoom=1&tbnh=93&tbnw=129&usg=__GKYfah2MHO_kP_wMJDI1C2xTIKg=&docid=XUnjeZM-HJwwkM&sa=X&ei=POG7U6O4D5PX7AbE6IDACQ&ved=0CDQQ9QEwAg&dur=29)